# How to push $variable into multidimensional array php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

How can i push variable into multidimensional array php? 
when I give key for the tow array it worked, but when I delete keys it doesn't work :
I mean :

```
$array1= array('x'=>array('id'=>7,'code'=>4444),'y'=>array('id'=>8,'code'=>3333));
```

whith

```
array_push($array1['x'],$newdata);
```

I dont want to generate x, y ... , I want let it automatically generated.

I want a result look like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [code] => 4444
            [newData] => 1111
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [code] => 3333
            [newData] => 1111
        )
```

)

Here what i tried:

```
<?php
$array1= array(array('id'=>7,'code'=>4444),array('id'=>8,'code'=>3333));
$newdata = 1111;
foreach ($array1 as $item ){
    array_push($item,$newdata);
}
print_r($array1);
```

Comment: Use a reference to `$item` in the foreach loop. (`foreach($array1 as &$item)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to be able to update the original array in the correct way.  Firstly to update the original data (in this way) use `&$item`.  Secondly add the item with the correct key rather than use just using `array_push()` - `array_push()` will add it with a key of `0` (in this case)...

```
foreach ($array1 as &$item ){
    $item['newData'] = $newdata;
}
```

gives the output...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [code] => 4444
            [newData] => 1111
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [code] => 3333
            [newData] => 1111
        )

)
```

Or using the original array and fetching the key in the foreach...

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item ){
    $array1[$key]["newData"] = $newdata;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That what I want exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use push. When for loop we need to use & symbol before $ to reference item variable

```
$array1= array(array('id'=>7,'code'=>4444),array('id'=>8,'code'=>3333));
$newdata = 1111;
foreach ($array1 as &$item ){
    $item["newData"] = $newdata;
}
print_r($array1);
```

Just do it this way.

Comment: Thank you so much. That what I want exactly. Thanks bro